# Javascript objects creation method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created an object named *computer* but it is giving me the error *Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer* and *Uncaught ReferenceError: computer is not defined*

What I can be done where I am going wrong? Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        computer = {drive: "floppy", cpu = "intel", ram: "ddr"}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(computer.drive);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: const computer = {drive: "floppy", cpu = "intel", ram: "ddr"}

Comment: you can also use `let` or `var` – `let computer = {drive ...` if you intend to make a change to the variable later on

Comment: @Bergur Almost.

Comment: You also have `cpu = "intel"` which should be `cpu: "intel"` – that is the invalid shorthand

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare it.

```
    const computer = {drive: "floppy", cpu: "intel", ram: "ddr"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. Invalid shorthand property initializer
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: computer is not defined

These sound scary but they are both quite straight forward to fix.

**Invalid shorthand property initializer**

```
{drive: "floppy", cpu = "intel", ram: "ddr"}
                      ^
```

This `=` should be a `:` like the other bits of your object. If you'd have Googled [this on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006503/invalid-shorthand-property-initializer) you would have been able to fix it yourself. The shorthand syntax is something else you can use, so if you wrote something like:

```
var cpu = "intel";
var computer = {drive: "floppy", cpu, ram: "ddr"}
```

That would be an example of **valid** shorthand, and is the same as writing

```
var cpu = "intel";
var computer = {drive: "floppy", cpu: cpu, ram: "ddr"}
```

**Uncaught ReferenceError: computer is not defined**

When we write `var` or `let` or `const` we are *declaring* variables. In your case, you just write:

```
computer = { ...
```

The error is telling you quite clearly that you haven't defined a variable called that, or it can't find one. This is a simple fix:

```
var computer = {
```

As a sidenote, notice that above when declaring a variable it is correct to use an equals sign, but when you are in an `{}` object, you should always use colons.