# Render component stored in record in React with dynamic string key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

This is something that is easy to work around, but I was wondering if this is possible. Is it achievable at all to render a React component by accessing an object with a dynamic key?

Trying the below shows that the expected way of doing it is invalid syntax in JSX. I understand I could store the active object in the map in the state or conditionally map the object entries, but I couldn't seem to find any questions regarding this and was hoping to see if anyone has any experience with this.

Thanks for your help.

Here's the setup I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import {ComponentOne, ComponentTwo, ComponentThree} from "../directory"

const map = {
  k1 = { name="Component 1", child=ComponentOne }
  k2 = { name="Component 2", child=ComponentTwo }
  k3 = { name="Component 3", child=ComponentThree }
}

const myComponent = () => {

  const [active, setActive] = useState("k1")

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {
          Object.entries(map).map(([k, v]) => 
            <h1 onClick={() => setActive(k)}>{ v.name }</h1>
          )
        }
      </div>
      <div>
        < map[active].child />
      </div>
    <>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid shorthand property initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006503/invalid-shorthand-property-initializer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All components in the end are functions or classes that you can get a reference to and therefore access dynamically through any object.

JSX is simply a unique syntax to call that function. So first get a reference to the React component and then use JSX to render the component.

**Solution Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo, ComponentThree } from "../directory";

const map = {
  k1: { name: "Component 1", child: ComponentOne },
  k2: { name: "Component 2", child: ComponentTwo },
  k3: { name: "Component 3", child: ComponentThree },
};

const myComponent = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("k1");

  // Store the reference to the component you want to render in a variable
  const ActiveChild = map[active].child;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        {Object.entries(map).map(([k, v]) => (
          <h1 onClick={() => setActive(k)}>{v.name}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* Since the variable holds reference to a React component, you can render it JSX syntax */}
        <ActiveChild />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you - I got so caught up in the syntax within the render that I completely forgot about the rest of the component for declaring the variable.